# Animation traces JavaFX line in both directions instead of only to the right

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I've written some code that generates a line in the upper right side of the caret in a TextArea and creates the following animation whenever i left click:

- at first, the line is a point (startXY and endXY coordinates are the
  same) and because of the round cap it looks like a circle
- the width of the "circle" increases from 1 to 16
- endX coordinate increases by 70 (so that it looks like the line is
  being traced)

I couldn't use an actual circle or any other shape for this because the round edges would also get distorted when expanding.

It's also necessary that this line is a child of a BorderPane, as are the other components of the project. I would also really prefer not using a JTextArea for this, since I have never used swing.

I'm only going to include the parts of the code that are relevant to this line because the whole project is quite long and messy, but I can assure you that Eclipse gives zero errors or warnings. The width increase works perfectly, but the line expands in both directions on the X axis instead of only modifying the endX coordinate.

I should also mention that I've tried testing the line expanding animation in a separate project (on a blank canvas in a Pane, if that helps) and it works exactly as intended.

Here's the project that doesn't work:

```
//coordinates of top-left corner of textarea:
        //X: 30
        //Y: 184


        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> eventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
               @Override
               public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                  TextAreaSkin skin = (TextAreaSkin) textarea.getSkin();
                  Bounds b = skin.getCaretBounds();
                  //coordinates of the upper tip of the caret, (0,0) being the top-left corner of textarea:
                  //b.getCenterX();
                  //b.getMinY();
                  int adjust = 7;
                  //type a space char (to which l should be tied, haven't written this part yet)
                  int spacep = textarea.getCaretPosition();
                  textarea.setText(textarea.getText().substring(0, spacep) + " " + textarea.getText().substring(spacep, textarea.getText().length()));

                  //growing animation
                  int sx = (int)(30 + b.getMaxX() + adjust);
                  int sy = (int)(184 + b.getMinY() + adjust-1);
                  int ex = (int)(30 + b.getMaxX() + adjust);
                  int ey = (int)(184 + b.getMinY() + adjust-1);
                  Line l = new Line(sx, sy, ex, ey);
                  l.setStroke(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
                  l.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.ROUND);
                  l.setStrokeWidth(1);
                  pane.getChildren().add(l);
                  ScaleTransition s = new ScaleTransition(Duration.millis(500), l);
                  s.setByX(16);
                  s.setByY(16);
                  s.setCycleCount(1);
                  s.setAutoReverse(false);


                  //elongating animation (not working properly!!!)
                Timeline t = new Timeline(
                        new KeyFrame(
                                Duration.millis(1000),
                                new KeyValue(l.endXProperty(), ex + 70)
                        )
                );
                t.setCycleCount(1);
                t.setAutoReverse(false);

                SequentialTransition sequentialTransition = new SequentialTransition();
                sequentialTransition.getChildren().addAll(
                        s,
                        t);
                sequentialTransition.setCycleCount(1);
                sequentialTransition.setAutoReverse(true);
                sequentialTransition.play();


               }
            };
        textarea.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, eventHandler);

        pane.setTop(lblbox);
        pane.setCenter(textarea);
        pane.setStyle(String.format("-fx-background-color: #%s;", s));
        BorderPane.setMargin(textarea, new Insets(30));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 500, 500));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Here's the test project (that works):

```
public class FXSample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    final int W = 800;
    final int H = 500;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.setTitle("Definition of Color");
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(W, H);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        Line l = new Line(200, 400, 200, 400);
        l.setStroke(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
        l.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.ROUND);
        l.setStrokeWidth(16);
        Timeline t = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(
                        Duration.millis(1000), 
                            new KeyValue(l.endXProperty(), 500)
            )
        );
        t.setCycleCount(2);
        t.play();

        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.getChildren().add(l);
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

As you can see from the first snippet, I've tried changing a lot of things to try and make it work, including casting the coordinates from double to int and creating separate variables for startXY and endXY, even though they have the same value in the beginning.

If you need more details, let me know! Sorry for the confusing wording BTW, I'm really new to java and my english is not the best.

Comment: “It's also necessary that this line is a child of a BorderPane…” A BorderPane, by definition, can only have five child nodes, one at each position.  Are you sure you can’t make a Group or StackPane the center child of your BorderPane?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! My textarea is already the center child, but I’ll try placing it in a group as well and report back when I’m at my computer again.

Comment: Update: apparently there is no pane/group that will clip its children automatically if it's the child of another pane/group. I even tried coding in a clipper by creating a rectangle and using the setClip() method before realising that it makes the rest of the textarea disappear.